# Regex Expression to extract county and zipcode

Tags: regex

Given the below text, I want to extract county, state and zipcode i.e. BROWNSBURG, IN 46112.
With my current Regex Expression --

```
text = "BROWNSBURG, IN 46112 10 Other income (loss) 15 Alternative minimum tax (AMT) items"
regex = ([A-z]*[\S][\s]{1}[A-z]{2}[\d\s]+)
output = BROWNSBURG, IN 46112 10
```

It is extracting BROWNSBURG, IN 46112 10, I don't want this redundant 10. Can anyone please suggest the change in the above regex as it is working fine for most of the documents?

Comment: When you say "county and zipcode", do you mean "city" (BROWNSBURG), "state" (IN), and "zipcode" (46112)?

Comment: Are you aware of the followed with the regex in the question? --- 1) `[\S]` is the same as `\S`. --- 2) `[\s]{1}` is the same as `\s`. --- 3) `[A-z]` matches characters other than letters, i.e. `[`, ``\``, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `\``.

Comment: Please include more sample text beyond this one trivial example.

Comment: @Andreas yes I'm aware of the with Regex. Yeah, I need to extract  "city" (BROWNSBURG), "state" (IN), and "zipcode".

Answer (score 1):

With only one example being provided, I will start out with assuming that the match you're looking for is always at the beginning of the line?

If so, it would be much safer to add the `^` anchor. Otherwise, you should remove it.

```
^[A-Z\s]+,\s[A-Z]{2}\s\d{5}
```

When we break down the pattern, you will see why this works:

- `^` asserts the beginning of the line *(remove if necessary)*
- `[A-Z\s]+` will match any letter or space that comes prior to the `,\s`. The space is important in the event of counties/cities that contain more than one word.
- `[A-Z]{2}` must match a 2-letter state code
- Then finally, `\d{5}` will match on the 5-digit zip code.

[Here is your custom view](https://regex101.com/r/sFAhJf/1) of your pattern in action.

Placing your pattern in a capturing group is unnecessary. You can simply return the full match, as it will be the same as the submatch. And while this one seems to be pretty simple, please understand that there are different implementations of Regular Expressions in different languages, so specifying the language in your question tags may prove to be useful in the future.